# Analog clock with moving hands with finger gesture unity3d

Tags: rotation, unity-game-engine, clock

I am making analog clock in unity3d. I am moving hands with finger gesture. I have code for moving the hands:

```
   void OnMouseDrag(){
        mouseClickPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        Vector3 dir = mouseClickPos - transform.position;
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y,dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        angle = Mathf.Round(angle/6f)*6f;
        hand1.transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);
    }
```

The problem is that I want to make hour hand move angle/10 at the same time when I move minute hand(if minute hand is moving for 6 degrees, hour hand should move for 0.6 degrees), but when I make full circle with minute hand, position of hour hand resets. It should work for bot sides.
Can someone help me please?

Comment: I think it's time you should track real time in your clock, not just angles (or at least the number of minutes from midnight).

Comment: How to track real time when rotating clock hands with OnMouseDrag?

Comment: I meant you should switch your logic from angle-based to a real time-based model. Your clock was at 10:15 and the minute hand moved by +90 degrees? Track that as a change of +15 minutes (that is `t=60*10+30` in minutes from midnight) and ajust the minute hand to `(t%60)*360` degrees and hour hand to `360*(t%12)/12f` degrees.

Comment: Not my day today, sorry. I see what do you want me to do, but I don't know how can I detect change because when I move finger around, I need to move hour hand from one hour to another(every time i move it it needs to skip 30 degrees)